# pure css menu, transition not working

Tags: html, css, menu, transition

I'm trying to create a purely css driven menu, and once the user hovers over a menu item, I would like the submenu to slide out from one side. I am trying to use transitions, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyIHg

If anyone could have a look, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this, might help: http://codepen.io/Cub3D/pen/moDqb

Comment: You can't transition between `display:none` and `display:block`. Try changing it so that your submenus sit *underneath* your main menu using z-index, than transition the left property instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RceP7/)

By way of some explanation, you need to remove setting the `display` on an element from `none/block/inline-block` when you wish to apply a transition, or the transition will not apply as you anticipate because it is not a computable sliding value  (the transition will just go from showing nothing to showing something instantly).

Change your CSS to (some tweaking required):

```
html, body {
    font-family:Calibri;
    background:#3d3d3d;
}
#test {
    display: block;
    width:80px;
    height:200px;
    background:lightsalmon;
}
#test a {
    display:block;
    width:80px;
    height:20px;
    color:#111111;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#test ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
}
#test ul li {
    height:20px;
    width:80px;
}
#test ul li ul {
    -o-transition: .3s;
    -ms-transition: .3s;
    -moz-transition: .3s;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    /* ...and the transition property */
    transition: .3s;
    transition:width .8s ease;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:0px;
    top:-20px;
    background:lightsalmon;
    position:relative;
    right:0;
    opacity:0;
}
#test ul li:hover {
    background:lightcoral;
}
#test ul li:hover ul {
    width:80px;
    left:80px;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you have done and why etc.... Bit more useful then a block of `CSS`.